# Replacing chandelier

Tags: wiring

I tried to change an old chandelier, but when I removed the ceiling rose all I have is an earth and one large brown cable and a block connector with red, blue and earth each side of connector but not attached to light.
[image]

Comment: Need more info. **Have you turned off the breaker to the box?**  Can you pull out the connector and the brown wire to see how they are wired to the house wiring and take a photo?

Comment: Also **PLEASE  ad the proper punctuation** to your question. Periods and commas and paragraph breaks are important and necessary.

Comment: I'm assuming you're in the UK, but it helps to be specific about your location in a question like this, as standards/practices vary worldwide.

Answer (score 2):

That "large brown" cable likely has 2 conductors inside that coming out of the brown jacket somewhere out of sight and then are connecting to that block.

Answer (score 0):

That brown cable is just snagged on something up in the box.  That may have been done deliberately as a stress relief.   It comes back out of the box, splits into its wires, and then goes down to the little connector and splices in there.

Green goes to bare, blue goes to blue, and lamp brown goes to whatever is left.